# Avoid sharing paid app with google account

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-lvl

I have implemented Android license verification to protect users sharing APK files of my paid app. But what if they purchase the app from one Google account share the account details with each other? Is there a way to determine if such a thing is happening and limit the number of devices that can download that app with one account or outright ban that Google account if they share the details with, let's say 5 devices or something like that? Does Google Play Console let me see what Gmail accounts are used to install the app? How can I avoid users sharing the account/app without implementing a fully blown sign in system of my own? I am not dealing with the most advanced hackers or anything. Just avoiding an average Joe sharing account details in a group chat is my goal.

Comment: I would not risk to block legitimate uses (and getting bad reviews for that reason) because of a few cheaters.

Comment: @Henry how would you address the issue in that case? What's stopping 100 people using the same account? My app doesn't have a large of number potential users anyway

Comment: This is bad idea. Customer can use your app by 1-10 devices. What the problem? If a user share account than second user can use all apps

Comment: @Style-7 do you think 100 people in a group chat should be able to use the same paid app by only purchasing it once? I think that's ludicrous.